# Что и как можно поменять/улучшить в коде разрабатываемой игры?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, инспекция-кода

Это моя первая игра на С++. Хотел бы услышать, что можно поменять, улучшить?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;


char field[3][3] = { ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' };  //массив, в котором храним поле

bool isOver;                //конец игры

short curI = 1, curJ = 1;   //текущая позиция курсора

char player = 'X';          //кто играет в данный момент?

bool IsBusy = false;        //флаг, сообщает об ошибке если true

bool Comp = false;          //флаг хода бота

bool PlayerT = false;       //флаг хода игрока

bool AllClosed = false;     //флаг доступных ячеек

char winner = ' ';          //победитель, сначала это пробел

void IsEven()
{

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (field[i][j] != ' ')
                counter++;
        }
    if (counter == 9)
    {
        counter = 0;
        AllClosed = true;
    }
    else
        counter = 0;
}

void check()    //проверяем, не победил ли кто?
{

    IsEven();

    if (AllClosed == true)
        winner = 'e';

    if ((field[0][0] == field[0][1] && field[0][1] == field[0][2] && field[0][0] == 'X') ||
        (field[1][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[1][2] && field[1][2] == 'X') ||
        (field[2][0] == field[2][1] && field[2][1] == field[2][2] && field[2][2] == 'X') ||
        (field[0][0] == field[1][0] && field[1][0] == field[2][0] && field[2][0] == 'X') ||
        (field[0][1] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][1] && field[2][1] == 'X') ||
        (field[0][2] == field[1][2] && field[1][2] == field[2][2] && field[2][2] == 'X') ||
        (field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][2] && field[2][2] == 'X') ||
        (field[0][2] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][0] && field[2][0] == 'X'))
    {
        winner = 'p';
    }if ((field[0][0] == field[0][1] && field[0][1] == field[0][2] && field[0][0] == 'O') ||
        (field[1][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[1][2] && field[1][2] == 'O') ||
        (field[2][0] == field[2][1] && field[2][1] == field[2][2] && field[2][2] == 'O') ||
        (field[0][0] == field[1][0] && field[1][0] == field[2][0] && field[2][0] == 'O') ||
        (field[0][1] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][1] && field[2][1] == 'O') ||
        (field[0][2] == field[1][2] && field[1][2] == field[2][2] && field[2][2] == 'O') ||
        (field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][2] && field[2][2] == 'O') ||
        (field[0][2] == field[1][1] && field[1][1] == field[2][0] && field[2][0] == 'O'))
    {
        winner = 'c';
    }

}

void DrawCell(short i, short j) //функция отрисовки ячейки
{
    if (i == curI && j == curJ)
        cout << ">";
    else
        cout << " ";
    cout << field[i][j];
    if (i == curI && j == curJ)
        cout << "<";
    else
        cout << " ";
}

void BestTurn() // лучший ход в игре, сначала проверяем его
{
    player = 'O';
    if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) // проверяем центральную ячейку
    {
        field[1][1] = player;
        Comp = true;
    }
}

void AlmostWon()  // проверяем, не близок ли игрок к победе
{
    if ((field[0][0] == field[0][1] && field[0][0] == 'X')) if (field[0][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][0] == field[0][2] && field[0][0] == 'X')) if (field[0][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][1] == field[0][2] && field[0][1] == 'X')) if (field[0][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][0] == 'X')) if (field[1][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][0] == field[1][2] && field[1][0] == 'X')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[1][2] && field[1][1] == 'X')) if (field[1][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[2][0] == field[2][1] && field[2][0] == 'X')) if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[2][0] == field[2][2] && field[2][0] == 'X')) if (field[2][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[2][1] == field[2][2] && field[2][1] == 'X')) if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    // проверка горизонтали

    if ((field[0][0] == field[1][0] && field[0][0] == 'X')) if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][0] == field[2][0] && field[0][0] == 'X')) if (field[1][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][0] == field[2][0] && field[1][0] == 'X')) if (field[0][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][1] == field[1][1] && field[1][0] == 'X')) if (field[2][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][1] == field[2][1] && field[0][1] == 'X')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[2][1] && field[1][1] == 'X')) if (field[0][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[1][2] && field[1][2] == 'X')) if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[2][2] && field[0][2] == 'X')) if (field[1][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][2] == field[2][2] && field[1][2] == 'X')) if (field[0][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    //проверка вертикали

    if ((field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[0][0] == 'X')) if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][0] == field[2][2] && field[0][0] == 'X')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[2][2] && field[1][1] == 'X')) if (field[0][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[1][1] && field[0][2] == 'X')) if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[2][0] && field[0][2] == 'X')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[2][0] && field[1][1] == 'X')) if (field[0][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    //проверка диагоналей
}

void AnswerTurn() // обычно это второй ход, "ответный, так сказать"
{
    //проверка угловых клеток
    if (field[0][0] == field[2][2] && field[0][0] == 'X' && !Comp) { field[1][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if (field[0][2] == field[2][0] && field[0][2] == 'X' && !Comp) { field[1][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
}

void CompCanWin()  // проверяем, можем лии мы выиграть
{
    if ((field[0][0] == field[0][1] && field[0][0] == 'O')) if (field[0][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][0] == field[0][2] && field[0][0] == 'O')) if (field[0][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][1] == field[0][2] && field[0][1] == 'O')) if (field[0][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][0] == field[1][1] && field[1][0] == 'O')) if (field[1][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][0] == field[1][2] && field[1][0] == 'O')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[1][2] && field[1][1] == 'O')) if (field[1][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[2][0] == field[2][1] && field[2][0] == 'O')) if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[2][0] == field[2][2] && field[2][0] == 'O')) if (field[2][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[2][1] == field[2][2] && field[2][1] == 'O')) if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    // проверка горизонтали

    if ((field[0][0] == field[1][0] && field[0][0] == 'O')) if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][0] == field[2][0] && field[0][0] == 'O')) if (field[1][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][0] == field[2][0] && field[1][0] == 'O')) if (field[0][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][1] == field[1][1] && field[1][0] == 'O')) if (field[2][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][1] == field[2][1] && field[0][1] == 'O')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[2][1] && field[1][1] == 'O')) if (field[0][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[1][2] && field[0][2] == 'O')) if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[2][2] && field[1][2] == 'O')) if (field[1][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][2] == field[2][2] && field[0][2] == 'O')) if (field[0][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    //проверка вертикали

    if ((field[0][0] == field[1][1] && field[0][0] == 'O')) if (field[2][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][0] == field[2][2] && field[0][0] == 'O')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[2][2] && field[1][1] == 'O')) if (field[0][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[1][1] && field[0][2] == 'O')) if (field[2][0] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[2][0] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[0][2] == field[2][0] && field[0][2] == 'O')) if (field[1][1] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[1][1] = player; Comp = true; }
    if ((field[1][1] == field[2][0] && field[1][1] == 'O')) if (field[0][2] == ' ' && !Comp) { field[0][2] = player; Comp = true; }
    //проверка диагоналей
}

void Computer_Turn()  // ход ИИ
{
    BestTurn();
    if (!Comp)
        AlmostWon();
    if (!Comp)
        CompCanWin();
    if (!Comp)
        AnswerTurn();
    check();
}

void Redraw() //функция перерисовки
{
    system("cls");    //очищаем экран
                      //исходя из стандартных размеров консоли
                      //будем рисовать пробулы и отступы
                      //чтоб все было посередине красивенько :)
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
        cout << " ";
    //рисуем ячейки
    DrawCell(0, 0);
    cout << "|";
    DrawCell(0, 1);
    cout << "|";
    DrawCell(0, 2);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "---+---+---" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
        cout << " ";
    DrawCell(1, 0);
    cout << "|";
    DrawCell(1, 1);
    cout << "|";
    DrawCell(1, 2);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "---+---+---" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
        cout << " ";
    DrawCell(2, 0);
    cout << "|";
    DrawCell(2, 1);
    cout << "|";
    DrawCell(2, 2);
    cout << endl;
    //выводим всякую информацию
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "Чтобы начать заново, нажмите N\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
        cout << " ";
    cout << "Чтобы выйти, нажмите Esc\n";
    if (IsBusy == true)     //если пытаемся пойти в занятую клетку
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
            cout << " ";
        cout << "Эта клетка уже занята!";
        IsBusy = false;
    }
    if (winner != ' ')    //если кто-то выиграл
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
            cout << " ";
        if (winner == 'p')
            cout << "Игрок  выиграл! Нажмите N";
        else  if (winner == 'c')
            cout << "Компьютер выиграл! Нажмите N";
        else if (winner == 'e')
            cout << "     Ничья! Нажмите N";
    }

}

void IfAv()
{
    if (field[curI][curJ] != ' ')
    {
        IsBusy = true;    //ошибочка - пользователь ставит
                          //символ в занятую клетку
                          //пишем сюда true (переменная-флаг)
        Redraw();
    }
}

bool ProcessInput()    //функция ввода
{
    int c = _getch();  //getch - находится в библиотеке
                       //conio.h и считывает код символа
    if (c == 27)       //если нажали esc
        return true;
    else if (c == 224) //при нажатии на любую из стрелок
                       //идет этот код, а после - разный
                       //его и проверяем далее
    {
        c = _getch();
        if (c == 75 && curJ > 0) //влево
        {
            curJ--;
            Redraw();
        }
        else if (c == 77 && curJ < 2) //вправо
        {
            curJ++;
            Redraw();
        }
        else if (c == 72 && curI > 0) //вверх
        {
            curI--;
            Redraw();
        }
        else if (c == 80 && curI < 2) //вниз
        {
            curI++;
            Redraw();
        }
    }
    else if (c == 32 && field[curI][curJ] == ' ')    //пробел
    {
        PlayerT = true;
        IfAv();
        field[curI][curJ] = 'X';
        check();
    }
    else if (c == 110)    //нажали N, начинаем сначала
    {
        for (short x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            for (short z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                field[x][z] = ' ';
        curI = 1;
        curJ = 1;
        winner = ' ';
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); // русский язык в консоль
    isOver = false;
    cout << "Правила игры: передвигаемся по полю стрелками клавиатуры" << endl;
    cout << "Ходим нажатием на пробел";
Sleep(2000);
    while (!isOver)                //пока не завершена игра
    {
        Redraw();
        while (!PlayerT)
            isOver = ProcessInput();
        if(PlayerT==true)
            Computer_Turn();
        Comp = false;
        PlayerT = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55659/discussion-on-question-by----------).

Answer (score 3):

Что можно улучшить:

- Прекратить использовать глобальные переменные. Сделайте нормальную передачу параметров между функциями. В том числе для того, чтобы можно было понять, что она принимает на вход и что выдает на выходе.

  Или, учитывая что речь идет о С++, возможно правильным решением будет свой отдельный "мирок" со своими внутренними "псевдо-глобальными" переменными, каковым в классическом ООП является *класс*.
- Избавьтесь от большинства "магических констант" в коде.
- Не мешало бы подумать, как избавиться от "стены кода" в функции `AlmostWon`. (А если бы вы шахматы реализовывали?)
- Смущает манера `if (IsBusy == true)`, при том, что вы умеете `while (!isOver)`. Но если уж вам так больше нравится... (Между строк: прекратите вакханалию и пишите как люди `if (IsBusy)` или `if (!IsBusy)`)
- `for (short x = 0; x < 3; x++)...` "Малые" арифметические типы предназначены для экономии памяти в массово инстанциируемых структурах данных. Если вы будете создавать 100500 мильёнов узлов какого-нибудь дерева, то заменить `int` на `short` в узле дерева может иметь смысл. В коде же программы использовать `short` для какой-то локальной переменной никакого смысла нет. Вопреки поверьям начинающих это ничего не "ускоряет" и не "экономит" (скорее наоборот). Пользуйтесь `int`/`unsigned int`/`size_t` в качестве умолчательных "повседневных" типов. `short` тут ни к чему.
- Режет глаз, конечно же, `system("cls")` и `<conio.h>`, но если у вас такое задание, то тут ничего не поделаешь.

  Однако, если вы уж вынуждены пользоваться нестандартными платформенно-зависимыми средствами, то заворачивайте их в отдельные функции - эдакий уровень отделения/абстракции от особенностей платформы. В частности, основной логике игры совсем не надо знать, что клавиши направления в Windows имеют "двойные" коды.
- `<Windows.h>` вам не нужен. (Ну зачем вам этот `Sleep(2000)`?) Я также подозреваю, что вы даже не знаете, что такое `"stdafx.h"`
- В коде, конечно, еще много проблем. (Код написан на слегка С++-фицированном С.) Но есть надежда, что процесс решения вышеперечисленных уже натурально повлечет за собой и переосмысление многих неназванных.

Comment: спасибо, попробую улучшить код, без "stdafx.h" студия отказывается компилить, она была изначально, я её не убирал.

Comment: @Сергей Омельчук: Это происходит потому, что у вас в настройках проекта включено использование прекомпилированных хедеров. (Скорее всего вы согласились на это при создании проекта). Выключите в настройках прекомпилированные хедеры, и `"stdafx.h"` можно будет убрать. Прекомпилированные хедеры - полезная фича, но вы ей здесь все равно не пользуетесь и вам она здесь ни к чему.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, убрал  две библиотеки, немного оптимизировал код, завтра еще буду над ним работать